# How to pass in struct fields as parameter in a function to display json data?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm working on a project to display json data and check if they are a leap year or not.

I'm trying to create a parameter for **IsLeapYear** so I can pass in some json values when doing the testing, I tried pointer to the struct with **User** so I can pass in the the fields in the function's parameter, but it didn't work.

How can I pass in a json data from user.json in a function parameter that would allow me to do testing much easier?

Just to let you know, I'm getting an error in my testing file, because I created DateTest which are strings, but **IsLeapYear** isn't a string.

Here's my code:

main.go:

```
  package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

// Users struct which contains
// an array of users
type Users struct {
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}

// User struct which contains a name
// a type and a list of social links
type User struct {
    Firstname  string `json:"fname"`
    Secondname string `json:"lname"`
    Date       string `json:"date"`
}

var users Users

func Birthday() {
    // Open our jsonFile
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("users.json")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened users.json")
    // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    // read our opened xmlFile as a byte array.
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    // we initialize our Users array
    // we unmarshal our byteArray which contains our
    // jsonFile's content into 'users' which we defined above
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &users)

    IsLeapYear(&users{Firstname: ""}, &users{Secondname: ""}) ---> passing the users fileds 
}

func IsLeapYear(firstname *Users, secondname *Users) {

    // we iterate through every user within our users array and
    // print out the user Type, their name
    for i := 0; i < len(users.Users); i++ {
        date, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02", users.Users[i].Date)
        if err != nil {
            date, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", users.Users[i].Date)
            // date, err = time.Parse("2006 01 02", users.Users[i].Date)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("unsupported date format:", err)
            }
        }

        // check if the date is a leap year, ex: 29 is not a leap year but 28th is !

        if date.Day()%400 == 0 || (date.Day()%4 == 0 && date.Day()%100 != 0) {
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, "is a Leap Year ✨ ✨ ✨")
            fmt.Println("TODAY IS NOT YOUR BIRTHDAY, but it's a leap year..!!!    ")
            fmt.Println("")

            // checking if the date.day matches today's date
            if date.Day() == time.Now().Day() {
                fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
                fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
                fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
                fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, "is a Leap Year ✨ ✨ ✨")
                fmt.Println("TODAY IS YOUR BIRTHDAY AND A Leap YEAR, Happy birthday !!!    ")

                // not ur birthday today because the date in the json doesn't match todays date
            }

        } else {
            fmt.Println("User Date: " + users.Users[i].Date)
            fmt.Println("User First Name: " + users.Users[i].Firstname)
            fmt.Println("User Second Name: " + users.Users[i].Secondname)
            fmt.Println(users.Users[i].Date, " is Not a Leap Year    ")
            fmt.Println("Your Date is neither a leap year nor your birthday..!!! ")

        }

    }

}

func main() {
    Birthday()

}
```

user.json:

```
{
    "users": [
      {
        "Fname": "Johnny",
        "Lname":"mane",
        "date":"1982/01/08"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Wayne",
        "Lname":"Bruce",
        "date":"1965/01/30"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Gaga",
        "Lname":"Lady",
        "date":"1986/03/08"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "radio",
        "Lname":"head",
        "date":"1988/02/29"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Mario",
        "Lname":"torres",
        "date":"1996/09/04"
      },
      
      {
        "Fname": "robert",
        "Lname":"Alex",
        "date":"1991/12/05"
      },
      {
        "Fname": "Julia",
        "Lname":"sevak",
        "date":"1991-03-28"

      },
      {
        "Fname": "feb",
        "Lname":"robert",
        "date":"1995-05-24"

      },
      {
        "Fname": "Liam",
        "Lname":"Noah",
        "date":"2002-10-04"

      },
      {
        "Fname": "karim",
        "Lname":"salim",
        "date":"2021/10/21"

      },

      {
        "Fname": "ahmed",
        "Lname":"mario",
        "date":"2021-10-24"

      }
     

    ]
  }
```

BD_test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

type dateTest struct {
    firstname, lastname, expected string
}

var DateTests = []dateTest{
    {"karim", "salim", "2001/09/24"},
    {"neno", "torres", "2001/14/44"},
    {"harry", "potter", "2011/10/02"},
}

func TestIsLeap(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range DateTests {
        output := IsLeapYear(test.firstname, test.lastname). ---> error here !
        expectedLeap := test.expected

        if output != expectedLeap {
            t.Errorf("Output %q not equal to expected %q", output, expectedLeap)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please come up with a minimal example.

Comment: The `IsLeapYear` input parameters are utterly illogical, they make no sense. Not only did you name them incorrectly, given their type, but the function's body isn't referencing them at all, not once. What's the point of the "firstname" "lastname" arguments if function's not gonna use them?

Comment: @mkopriva yeah you're definitely right, I've been stuck here for a while now, I wrote my function without parameters so therefore I can't do unit testing, that's why I was playing around trying to come up with a solution,  but thank you for this, that was absolutely stupid of me! .....what would you recommend me to do in this case if I wanna perform unit testing with this function! should I rewrite the code again ? or should I put all the script in one function... I divided the functions respectively each with its own task! I thought this is better!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i apply unit testing to check leap year with golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69673616/how-do-i-apply-unit-testing-to-check-leap-year-with-golang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I cleaned up your code. Now the test should be easier to write

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

// Data struct which contains
// an array of users
type Data struct {
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}

// User struct which contains the first + last name and the birthdate
type User struct {
    FirstName  string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName string `json:"last_name"`
    Date       string `json:"date"`
}

func IsLeapYear(date time.Time) bool {
    return date.Day()%400 == 0 || (date.Day()%4 == 0 && date.Day()%100 != 0)
}

func parseDate(date string) time.Time {
    parsedDate, err := time.Parse("2006/01/02", date)

    if err != nil {
        parsedDate, err = time.Parse("2006-01-02", date)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("unsupported date format:", err)
        }
    }

    return parsedDate
}

func CheckBirthdateOf(user User) {
    date := parseDate(user.Date)

    fmt.Println("User Date: " + user.Date)
    fmt.Println("User First Name: " + user.FirstName)
    fmt.Println("User Last Name: " + user.LastName)

    if IsLeapYear(date) {
        fmt.Println(user.Date, "is a Leap Year ✨ ✨ ✨")

        if date.Day() == time.Now().Day() {
            fmt.Println("TODAY IS YOUR BIRTHDAY AND A Leap YEAR, Happy birthday !!!    ")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("TODAY IS NOT YOUR BIRTHDAY, but it's a leap year..!!!    ")
        }

    } else {
        fmt.Println(user.Date, " is Not a Leap Year    ")
        fmt.Println("Your Date is neither a leap year nor your birthday..!!! ")
    }

    fmt.Println("")
}

func main() {
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("users.json")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened users_data.json")
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    var usersData Data
    json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &usersData)

    for _, user := range usersData.Users {
        CheckBirthdateOf(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't turn SO into a code writing service, doubly so when the question looks like homework

Comment: @DanielFarrell You are right. Today it just didn't go quite so well for me and I wasn't really focused. I guess I thought that using the cleaned up code the OP would still need to research how to fix the test, which is what was originally asked for.